# Restricting public Access to S3 Website and allow access Authenticated Users from AWS Cognito User Pool via Hosted UI Link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have a static website hosted in Amazon S3 with public access. Recently, I created an AWS Cognito user pool and configured Google as the identity provider. Currently, when I click on the hosted UI link, it prompts me to enter credentials or sign in with Google, and then it displays the website.

The issue I'm facing is that the website is also accessible using the S3 URL by anyone, bypassing the Cognito authentication. I want to restrict access to this S3 website only for users from the Cognito user pool who access it through the hosted UI link.

How can I achieve this? What steps or configurations should I implement to ensure that only authenticated users from the Cognito user pool can access the S3 website via the hosted UI link?

I attempted to use several S3 bucket policies to allow access only to the Cognito domain.
I created an identity pool in Cognito and assigned my previous Cognito user pool to it.
I also created an IAM role with permissions to access my S3 website and attached it to the Cognito user pool.